# In Luminous Distance calculations, why does the power fall of by a factor of $(1+z)$?

Tags: cosmology, distance

This is a follow up to this question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/469371/why-is-the-relation-between-luminosity-distance-d-l-and-comoving-distance-ch/543089#543089) about the $(1+z)$ factor in the Luminous Distance formula.  As the universe expands, I understand why the energy falls as the wavelength is stretched (by a factor of $z+1$), but in the Luminous Distance formula
$$L_D=\chi(1+z)$$
we have an additional an additional factor of $z+1$.  I've read Dodelson and [this](https://cds.cern.ch/record/1184207/files/p187.pdf) article (page 201) and both seem to argue that the frequency of photons crossing the shell is different between emission and observation:

> We must take into account the fact that the rate of photon reception
>   is smaller than the rate of emission by a factor of $a = 1/(1+z)$.

Both authors wave their hands and say 'this is so', but I don't understand the process.  The time interval, $\Delta t$, is the same from emission to observation (that is, expansion doesn't change the time interval).  The number of photons crossing the entire shell doesn't change (you can't add or remove photons from the expanding shell).  So how does the rate of photons crossing the shell (or hitting a detector) change?

Comment: My guess is that if your shell is moving away from the flux of photons the number that photons that cross it per unit time is reduced by that factor.

Comment: You can't *'move away'* from flux.  Flux is the number of photons that cross your shell in a given unit of time.  That is, it's a measurement, not a 'thing'.

Comment: That is just time dilation.

Comment: @RobJeffries - What attribute of Hubble flow dilates time?  Is the $\Delta t_{EMISSION}$ different than the $\Delta t_{OBSERVATION}$?

Comment: If the wavelength goes up, the frequency goes down. This is cosmological time dilation. All frequencies are affected by the same factor, including the frequency with which photons are emitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The additional $1+z$ factor is cosmological time dilation (e.g. see [Zhang et al. 2013](https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.5612)).  The frequency with which photons are received is reduced by this factor.

That is, if a distant source emits $n$ photons per second in its rest frame, then those are received in the current epoch at a rate of $n/(1+z)$. The reason is precisely the same reason that individual photons have frequencies reduced by the same factor.

Comment: **Cosmic Time Dilation** doesn't appear to be a thing.  I can't find it in Dodelson, yet he appears to employ this idea of decreased frequence in his discussion of Luminous Distance.  I find less than half a dozen papers using a Google Search, there are no Wiki pages and there are various opinions that suggest it either doesn't exist, or is a different way of saying Redshift.  Do you have an authoritative paper (reference) I could read on the subject.

Comment: The  Zhang paper says "We have a theory, here's are attempt to prove or disprove it."  There's NO discussion of the theory.  I understand how space is expanded by the FLRW metric.  Where is the foundation that explains why time is compressed?

Comment: You seem to be arguing in this post (https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/300365/time-dilation-of-distant-cosmic-events-what-is-it#300375) that Cosmological Time Dilation is indistinguishable from Redshift.  Choose one or the other.  Either the wavelength is red shifted or the frequency is shortened.  We've already counted the impact of the redshifting on the energy of the photon.  Dodelson appears to be arguing that the second factor of (z+1) is related to the power (energy per unit time) measured by the detectors.

Comment: Nope. That isn't how it works. The frequency of light is reduced and the frequency with which individual photons are emitted is reduced by the same factor.

Comment: Indeed my previous answer is showing the same thing measured in supernova light curves. They are dilated by a factor of $1+z$ in addition to the photons being redshifted by $1+z$. The Zhang paper does the same for GRBs. Those trying to argue it doesn't happen (uncited in fringe journals?) are trying to overthrow the idea of FLRW cosmology.

Comment: I'd appreciate some background material.  I understand how the wavelength is redshifted by the expansion of space in the FLRW metric.  I've never seen a similar treatment for time.  Do you have a reference for this?  Not a paper that tries to prove the hypothesis, but a description of how the hypothesis flows from the FLRW metric.

Comment: It is exactly the same reason. The two phenomena are exactly the same. @GluonSoup If you like you can imagine the distance between photons being stretched by the same factor that their wavelengths are.